# IIS 7.5 Error 500.19 but sporadically

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, iis-7.5

I have Windows 2008 Sever R2, SQL Server 2008 with SSRS (not R2).  I have the reportserver working, but sporadically it will give me this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

I have another asp.net application with the same issue, so I assume the issue is similar.  It works probably 60% of the time, then just won't.  After awhile it just starts working again :(  Both SSRS and the application fail and work at the same time... so if one fails, both do.  One works, both do.

It is very frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worker process identity (Your application Pool User) and/or the IIS_IUSRS group needs at least Read access to the directory as well as the web.config file.

Use [Process Monitor tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to trace the Access Denied

Comment: Could you please comment on which directory/file you had to change permissions on?